# Show/Hide Contents of ContentPanel in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want my App Logo to be visible when a user starts the app for 5 secs and then take him to the Application. I am doing something like this.

**MainPage.xaml**:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" LayoutUpdated="ContentPanel_LayoutUpdated">
            <Image Name="startLogo" Source="/Assets/startScreen.png"></Image>
            <phone:WebBrowser Name="webView"
                              IsScriptEnabled="True"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              IsGeolocationEnabled="True"
                              ScriptNotify="webView_ScriptNotify"
                              NavigationFailed="webView_NavigationFailed"
                              Navigated="webView_Navigated"
                              Navigating="webView_Navigating"
                              SizeChanged="webView_SizeChanged"
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                </phone:WebBrowser>

</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**:

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            startLogo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            webView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            Thread displayStartScreen = new Thread(() =>
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    startLogo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                    webView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                });
            });
            displayStartScreen.Start();
        }
```

But with this, Application shows nothing for first 5 secs and then displays `webView`
What am i doing wrong here. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Thread.Sleep(5000); do this. Thread.sleep will block current thread during 5 sec

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you please elaborate

Comment: If you remove your thread, your logo is display correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the error. Putting

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

inside dispatcher was putting my Main Thread on sleep. I just removed it from there and put it before the line

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
```

This will put the `displayStartScreen` thread on sleep not the Main one. Working fine now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Thread.Sleep(5000);` is blocking the whole UI thread event before the startLogo is shown. When the sleep stops it shows the webView right await.

please try replacing the dispatcher with the following code:

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    startLogo.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    webView.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
});
```

That way only the dispatcher will be on hold and the Logo will be shown for 5 seconds.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with this but there is no `Task` inside dispatcher.  Anyways I got the error. Will put it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: Please add `using System.Threading.Tasks;` to your usings and see if it works.

Comment: Oh yes. Worked. Thanks